# How do I get this web-based word processor?

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if I could get a web-based word processor just like the one here on stack overflow, that shows a view of what you are typing in.

Answer (score 3):

The editor used on StackOverflow is a modified version of WMD: http://wmd-editor.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://wmd-editor.com/examples/splitscreen

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a lot of the same functionality.  I think SO wrote their own, though.

Comment: I've used TinyMCE and liked it.  However, a check of the SO Blog shows that driis & Kemo are correct in that WMD is the SO editor.

Comment: Actually TinyMCE and WMD is quite different editors. WMD is a Markdown editor, meaning you enter plain text, optionally with Markdown formatting syntax, and the editor converts it to HTML for preview. TinyMCE is a WYSIWYG HTML editor, where you are editing the actual HTML, and it then helps the user via some toolbuttons used to apply formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TinyMCE and make a function that gets the content of the TinyMCE editor box and  creates a preview below it  on every keystroke :)